# Amazon S3 on PHP GAE not working with curl extension

Tags: php, google-app-engine, amazon-s3

Could anyone help me figure out how to get S3 working on my php app engine (`runtime: php55`)?

I saw somewhere that you can use it without CURL and found the StreamWrapper but keep getting errors.

```
Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST
Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT
Use of undefined constant CURLE_PARTIAL_FILE
etc..
```

Here is my code:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

// Instantiate an S3 client
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array('key' => 'KEY','secret' => 'SECRET'));
$s3->registerStreamWrapper(); // don't use curl

//AMAZON S3 BACKUP//
$document_data = "123456";
$s3_object_url = "s3://bucket/folder/file.txt";
$s3_options = stream_context_create(['s3'=>['ACL'=>'bucket-owner-full-control', 'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256']]);
$s3_file = fopen($s3_object_url, 'w', false, $s3_options);
fwrite($s3_file, $document_data);
fclose($s3_file);
```

Error when using curl lite:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\CurlLiteMethodNotSupportedException' with message 'curl_multi_init' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLiteStub.php:1391
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/apps/.../vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(50): curl_multi_init()
#1 /base/data/home/apps/.../vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(128): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->__construct(1)
#2 /base/data/home/apps/.../vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(87): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->getAvailableHandle()
#3 /base/data/home/apps/.../vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(284): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->send()
#4 /base/data/home/apps/.../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(256): Guzzle\Http\Client->send(Ob in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/CurlLiteStub.php on line 1391
```

Error when using `extension = "curl.so"` in php.ini

> 15:09:52.614  A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

### EDIT:

It looks like "guzzle" needs curl enabled so I enabled `extension = "curl.so"` in my php.ini and it works fine in my localhost developer with no errors. But not when I upload it to app engine.

Comment: what errors do you see if you enable curl_lite? Those constants are definitely defined.

Comment: @StuartLangley I edited my question to show the error using curl_lite

Comment: V3 of the AWS SDK for PHP will not require cURL. It's still in beta.

Comment: can you also show error for using curl?

Comment: @Mars Added it to the question, do you have any suggestions or guidance on what the error may mean?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please file an issue @ https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language%3DPHP

Comment: Meanwhile, guzzle no longer needs curl: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html so you might want to try disable curl.

Answer (score 0):

curl requires sockets which are only available to bill enabled apps (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/). You may wish to also consider "curl lite": https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini#GAE_directives

Comment: I've tried both "curl lite" and enabled curl altogether. I should mention, I am using a bill enabled app. Do I need to enable "sockets" or should it already be enabled? Unless it's like an on-off switch, I don't see how my above code will be affected. Please note the edit, where I said it works on Dev server but not on deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Even though GAE supports "cURL" - it is only a wrapper, so some functionality has not been implemented yet - particularly the whole `multi_curl_*` thing.

Have not found a way to deactivate it - but from SDK v3 cURL is not anymore required - so you might give that a try.