# Posting to app engine app, getting 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine, curl

I've got an app engine app set up. It's set up with billing and I have extension="curl.so" in my php.ini file so I think cUrl should work. It is set up to allow cross domain requests.

I'm attempting to send data (via a jquery ajax post) to the app, then have it use curl to send the data somewhere else.

If I send no data with the ajax request, the curl works and the final destination responds telling app engine that there's no data, app engine successfully passes it back to the ajax callback (as expected).

However if I send data along, the app engine responds with a 500 error. It appears to be breaking during the curl_exec.

Everything works fine if I run it through the local server.

Does anyone have any idea what might be inhibiting app engine from allowing this?

Comment: Do you see any error in your log?

Comment: Yes: A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992685/amazon-s3-on-php-gae-not-working-with-curl-extension  Do you have a simple script to reproduce the problem reliably?