# Amazon SES error: "Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Could anyone please shed some light on what would be causing these errors?

I'm using Google App Engine on a development server. First I got this error:

> The email was not sent. Error message: Error executing "SendEmail" on
>   "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: No system CA
>   bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations. PHP
>   versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the
>   system's CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates,
>   you will need to supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to
>   the 'verify' request option:
>   http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not
>   need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly
>   used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the
>   maintainer of cURL):
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt.
>   Once you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the
>   'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file,
>   allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. See
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.

Then I added `google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = 1` to php.ini and reduced the error to:

> The email was not sent. Error message: Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: curl_multi_init

I'm beginning to understand that using SES on GAE might require a few tweaks??? What can I do?

My code is 99% from the Amazon documentation. The only difference is that I've hardcoded the credentials array in `$client`.

```
<?php

// Replace path_to_sdk_inclusion with the path to the SDK as described in
// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html
define('REQUIRED_FILE','../aws/aws-autoloader.php');

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
define('SENDER', 'me@verified.sender.address.com');

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
define('RECIPIENT', 'me@verified.receiver.address.com');

// Replace us-west-2 with the AWS region you're using for Amazon SES.
define('REGION','us-west-2');

define('SUBJECT','Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)');
define('BODY','This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.');

require REQUIRED_FILE;

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',
    'region' => REGION,
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret'  => 'xxx',
    )
));

$request = array();
$request['Source'] = SENDER;
$request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
$request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
$request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = BODY;

try {
    $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
    $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
    echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ");
    echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
}

?>
```

**EDIT:**

Once deployed, this works without any edit to php.ini...??

Comment: Looks like the issue is with GAE and V2 of the SDK... similar problems with S3: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28992685/1695906